# Show that $f(x, y) : = x^y$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (0, +\infty) \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the exponential function $f(x, y) : = x^y$ . Show that $f$ is continuous. (Hint: The easiest way to proceed is to write $f(x,y) = \exp(y\ln(x))$ and use the continuity $\exp()$ and $\ln()$.)

I know that $f\oplus g : X \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f\oplus g(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ is continuous if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and I also know that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous, and that the product of two continuous functions is continuous.

I was trying to prove the question using these results, but I couldn't manage to do it. I appreciate if you give some hint.

Edit: Suppose that there exists a continuous function $h:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x): = y$. Then, $\exp(y\ln(x)) = \exp \circ (h\cdot\ln)(x)$. This allows me to use the properties above, and it shows that  $f(x,y)$ is jointly continuous. But, I am not sure if I can simply argue that there exists a continuous function $h$. If I am not allowed to proceed in this way, how can I use properties to finish the proof?

Comment: With the hint in hand, this amounts to writing $\exp (y \ln x)$ using only direct sums, compositions, and products of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\pi_1(x,y) = x$ and $\pi_2(x,y) = y$. These maps are continuous (it's a very simple direct $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument). Now, $f(x,y) = x^y = \exp(y\ln(x))$ can be expressed using only elementary oprations of product and composition as follows:
\begin{align}
f &= \exp \circ [\pi_2 \cdot (\ln \circ \pi_1)]
\end{align}
(of course on the RHS, we restrict the domain of $\pi_1,\pi_2$ to $(0,\infty)\times \Bbb{R}$). Here,  $\pi_2$ and $\ln\circ\pi_1$ are continuous so their product is also continuous. Hence finally the composition with $\exp$ is also continuous (actually the same argument shows $f$ is $C^{\infty}$; just replace every instance of "continuous" with $C^{\infty}$)

Answer (score 0):

Now $ g(x)=ln(x),h(y)=y$ both are continuous over specified domains, hence $l(x)=yln(x)$ and $exp(x)$ are also continuous. Applying composition after this gives you the answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry it should be $\mathbb{R}^2$.